# Bypass Cloudflare Warp for specific domains that use geolocation

Tags: cloudflare-warp

Whenever I connect to Cloudflare Warp, it creates an IPv6 address for me, which my ISP does not provide. I end up with two IP addresses: IPv4 that geolocates to Canada, and IPv6 that geolocates to the United States.

I live in Canada, and certain websites I access require that I be in Canada and block my access if they think I am not. Because my IPv6 address is geolocated to the US, I end up having to disconnect and reconnect Cloudflare Warp in order to access this website.

I have tried adding a domain exception to both "Split Tunnel" and "Local Domain Fallback", but neither of those has worked. Anyone know how I can set up Cloudflare Warp so I don't have to disconnect it all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what I am trying to do **may not be possible**.

This is the response I received from Cloudflare Community Forum:

[image: Cloudflare Community Response]